# How do I find all permutations from a series of arrays that act as rows and columns in javascript?

Tags: javascript, arrays, path, permutation

**Here is my example data structure:**

r stands for row.

```
var data = {
  r0: ["E9", "55", "1C"],
  r1: ["1C", "E9", "E9"],
  r2: ["BD", "1C", "55"]
}
```

How would I go about finding all of the paths where paths cannot be the same, paths can only traverse starting horizontally (and only starting in row 0), then vertically, then horizontally, etc., during a path it cannot pick the same value. Paths can "jump" values though, if a valid value is detected in the current row/column.

**Rows** and **columns** start at **index 0**.

Examples of expected paths output from future algorithm:

```
RowColumn(value),....

// these paths stop because there are no more valid vertical or horizontal values to pick.
00(E9), 10(1C), 11(E9), 01(55), 02(1C), 22(55), 12(E9)
02(1C), 22(55), 20(BD), 00(E9), 01(55), 21(1C), 11(E9), 10(1C), 12(E9)
```

Comment: How would you do this if you had to do it by hand?  Once you have that figured out, you then just need to learn to convert it to code.

Comment: Can you elaborate on the final result? It seems like what you need is to flatten your `data` array

Comment: if you want only go right and down, you can go only a single path. what result do you want?

Comment: I've made the algorithm for it, only to discover that there was no solution :'( If you have to go horizontally, then vertically, then horizontally and so on, there is no way to make this work in a 3x3 grid. Your expected result does not follow that rule (you go horizontally twice in a row: `02, 12, 22`)

Comment: Looks like I completely glossed over the vertical-horizontal-vertical-etc. part... We need more clarification here; @blex is correct in that covering all elements in your 3x3 grid is impossible when you *must* alternate vertical/ horizontal every move. It feels like some info might be missing.

Comment: I made the mistake of accidentally writing 2 vertical moves (as pointed out by blex).
The goal is not to cover the entire 3x3 (or bigger) grid, but to find all possible paths starting from the first row. Paths can be any number of lengths. One must start from the first row going horizontally (picking any value), then picking a vertical value (all the while not picking any values already picked). Paths can "jump" over itself, but not pick the same value.

Comment: @Machineman1357 Oh, ok, being able to jump over cells and return an incomplete path works better. I've edited my answer to reflect that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Rules used in this answer

When reading your question, I understood that the rules were:

- start from `0_0`
- start by going horizontally
- alternate horizontal/vertical on every move
- never visit the same cell twice
- we can jump over cells that have already been visited
- the paths don't have to cover the entire grid

#### Algorithm

To get every path following these rules, you can use a recursive function *(a function which calls itself)*.

In the following example, it takes 2 parameters:

- **path**: an Array of visited cells
- **horizontal**: a Boolean describing whether we should move horizontally or not

The first time we call it, we give it a path containing the first cell (`['0_0']`), and `true` because we have to move horizontally.

It would then:

- find the cells in the same row or col as the last visited cell which have not yet been added to the path (horizontally or vertically depending on the current direction)
- call itself for each of these *nextCells*, adding that cell to the path and switching direction

#### Code

```js
function rowColumn(obj) {
  // Convert the Object to a 2D Array
  const data = Object.values(obj),
        rows = data.length,
        cols = data[0].length,
        res  = [];
  
  function recursive(path, horizontal) {    
    // Get the row or column cells that haven't been visited yet
    const nextCells = getNextCells(path, horizontal);
    
    // If no neighbors were found, push the result and return
    if (!nextCells.length) return res.push(path);
    
    // Apply recursion for all possible neighbors
    nextCells.forEach(cell => recursive(path.concat(cell), !horizontal));
  }
  
  function getNextCells(path, horizontal) {
    const [x, y] = path[path.length - 1].split('_').map(v => +v);
    let cells = [];
    
    if (horizontal) cells = Array.from({length: cols}, (_, i) => `${i}_${y}`);
    else            cells = Array.from({length: rows}, (_, i) => `${x}_${i}`);

    // Remove the cells that have already been visited
    return cells.filter(p => !path.includes(p));
  }
  
  // Start the recursion
  recursive(['0_0'], true);
  // Format the result
  return res.sort((a, b) => a.length - b.length)
            .map(path => path.map(cell => {
              const [x, y] = cell.split('_').map(v => +v);
              return `${x}${y}(${data[y][x]})`;
            }));
}

const data = {
  r0: ["E9", "55", "1C"],
  r1: ["1C", "E9", "E9"],
  r2: ["BD", "1C", "55"],
};

const res = rowColumn(data);
console.log(
  `There are ${res.length} paths possible:`,
  res.map(path => path.join(' '))
);
```

Comment: The algorithm works perfectly well done blex! All I personally added was create a loop to pass in all of the cells in the first row, to really get ALL the permutations (not just starting from 0_0).
Can you tell me how you came up with the solution? For a while I had been banging my head against the wall messing with for loops and briefly meddling in recursive functions, but to no avail. Are there some exercises, problems, or perhaps courses that you have taken that enabled you to create such an algorithm? Thank you

Comment: Great! Oh, I didn't get that part, I thought that all paths had to start at `0_0`

Comment: I don't understand why you are creating another const variable named res in the 'getNextCells' function when there is already one made at the top of the main function. I removed it for testing, and had an infinite loop. Can you explain to me why you made that variable and what significance it has as in what it does exactly?

Comment: The first one has nothing to do with the second one, they are in different scopes. The one in `rowColumn` stores the paths as they are discovered. The one in `getNextCells` stores the neighbors we find for a particular cell, in a particular direction. But now that I'm looking back at the code, this `getNextCells` function could be improved. I edited it and named the variable `cells`, if that can reduce the confusion

Answer (score 0):

```js
// Trying to replicate output 00(E9), 10(1C), 11(E9), 01(55), 02(1C), 12(E9), 22(55), 21(1C), 20(BD)

const algo = (values) => {
  // Find the number of keys of the values/data object
  const totalKeys = Object.keys(values).length

  // Cycle through the keys with an assumption that the first key is always 'r0'
  for (let row = 0; row < totalKeys; row++) {
    // construct a key name
    const keyName = "r" + row

    // get the array associated with this key
    const arr = values[keyName]

    // loop through the array
    for (let column = 0; column < arr.length; column++) {
      // get the current value
      const value = arr[column]

      // do whatever you want to do with values, I am just printing them here
      console.log("" + row + column + "(" + value + ")")
    }
  }
}

const data = { // usage of var is discouraged, use let or const instead
  r0: ["E9", "55", "1C"],
  r1: ["1C", "E9", "E9"],
  r2: ["BD", "1C", "55"]
}

algo(data);
```